# Why I can't print 0 with %7.d or other %x.d in C

Tags: c

Can someone help me in printing `0` with `%x.d` i.e. `%1.d`, `%2.d`, `%3.d`, etc.
Actually if I'm printing `0` with `%7.d` and it is not showing on terminal. You can visit [My GitHub](https://github.com/AmanRathoreM/All-in-C/blob/main/Problems/problem_1_printing_0_with_%25x_dot_d.c) for more reference.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num_1 = 0;
    int num_2 = 10000;
    int num_3 = 999;

    printf("Value of \'num_1\' is = %7.d\n", num_1);
    printf("Value of \'num_2\' is = %7.d\n", num_2);
    printf("Value of \'num_3\' is = %7.d\n", num_3);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Try `%7d` instead of `%7.d`  The `.` indicates that the "precision" is to *follow*, i.e. the number of digits of precision.  Since the precision value is missing, it is taken to be zero.

Comment: @TomKarzes but tom but taking the 7 value into consideration. it should have at least printed 6 spaces followed by a 0. can you explain more on this. why it's missed for 0 but for others it worked fine.

Comment: I think the issue is that 0 doesn't need *any* digits to represent, so when you use `%7.d`, which is equivalent to `%7.0d`, you don't get any digits of *precision*.  What you get is 7 spaces.  If you wrap the format in some visible delimeters, e.g. `<%7.d>`, you can see that it is *not* empty, it's just blank.  If you change it to `%7.1d` it will force at least one digit, which will make zero appear as `0` rather than blank.  You'll still get 7 characters total.

Comment: @PraneethKumar With the `i` and `d` conversion specifiers, when both the value and the precision are 0, as in your example, the conversion results in no characters. The padding is still there, that's the `7` part.

Comment: @Aman Why `%7.d` instead of `%7d`? What are you hoping for with that `.`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. For future question please remember to include your output together with expected output. Your statement "it is not showing on terminal" is not really useful. It could mean a line with 7 spaces or nothing at all which are very different things. Therefore please try to be precise and add all relevant information.

Answer (score 4):

The `printf` conversion specifier `%7.d`, equivalent to `%7.0d`, will convert an argument of type `int` to its decimal representation with at least `0` digits and pad it with initial spaces up to at least 7 characters.

As a special case, converting the argument value `0`, yields **no** digits and the output will be seven spaces.

You probably do not want these semantics as you expect `0` to produce       `0`, so you should not specify a *precision* field with a `.`. Use `%7d` instead.

Note also that the `\` in front of `'` is not required in a C string, but it is in the C character constant `'\''`

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int num_1 = 0;
    int num_2 = 10000;
    int num_3 = 999;

    printf("Value of 'num_1' is = %7d\n", num_1);
    printf("Value of 'num_2' is = %7d\n", num_2);
    printf("Value of 'num_3' is = %7d\n", num_3);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Value of 'num_1' is =       0
Value of 'num_2' is =   10000
Value of 'num_3' is =     999
```